# How to get the same part of file content?

Tags: python

I have two files , and I want to display the content exist in file 1 and file 2 in the screen. But it seems nothing display ( but it should display `オレンジ`) . What is the problem?

thanks

```
File 1

リンゴ
バナナ
オレンジ

File 2

オレンジ
```

Here is my code

```
import sys

File1 = open(sys.argv[1],"r",encoding="UTF-8")
F1_Content = File1.readlines()
F1_Content = map(lambda e : e.rstrip("\n"),F1_Content)

File2 = open(sys.argv[2],"r",encoding="UTF-8")
F2_Content = File2.readlines()
F2_Content = map(lambda e : e.rstrip("\n"),F2_Content)

for line in F1_Content:
    print(repr(line))
    if line in F2_Content:
        print(line)

File1.close()
File2.close()
```

Output

```
'\ufeff
''
''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have more whitespace in one of the files than just a newline. You could loop over either `F1_Content` and `F2_Content`, printing the *representation* of that line with `print(repr(line))` or `print(line.encode('unicode_escape'))` to make it easier to spot how the lines differ.

I'd strip the lines entirely. Also, use a `set` for the lines of one file, testing will be *much* more efficient:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as file1:
    f1_content = {line.strip() for line in file1}

with open open(sys.argv[2], "r") af file2:
    for line in file2:
        if line.strip() in file2:
            print(line)
```

Looping directly over the file itself reads the file line by line, letting you handle file lines without having to read the whole file into memory.

Note also the use of `with` statements here; file objects are context managers, and when the context closes (the `with` block ends) the file object is automatically closed for you.

With Katakana, there is also the possibility that one of your files uses decomposition for the  ZI character while the other does not; you can either express it as `\u30B8` **or** as `\u30B7\u3099`; (SI + COMBINING KATAKANA-HIRAGANA VOICED SOUND MARK):

```
>>> print('\u30B8 != \u30B7\u3099:', '\u30B8' != '\u30B7\u3099')
ジ != ジ: True
```

You can use [`unicodedata.normalize()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) to normalize all your lines to either composed or decomposed forms. Here I force all data to use composed forms:

```
from unicodedata import normalize

with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as file1:
    f1_content = {normalize(line.strip(), 'NFKC') for line in file1}

with open open(sys.argv[2], "r") af file2:
    for line in file2:
        if normalize(line.strip(), 'NFKC') in file2:
            print(line)
```

Comment: I think there are no white spaces in each line

Comment: @user2131116: Can you show us what `repr(line)` shows when looping over the file contents?

Comment: @user2131116: You can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19174650/edit) to add that information.

Comment: @user2131116: That's quite logical, because you only print when the lines match. But they don't match, so you'll never see that print statement. Move the `print()` to *before* the `if`. Use `print(line.encode('utf8'))`, perhaps, or even better,  `print(line.encode('unicode_escape'))`